# Como listar e excluir Variaveis no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, variáveis

Sei que é um pergunta bem básica, mas não consigo um resposta bem direta na internet.

Gostaria de saber como listar e excluir variáveis no MySQL.

Desde ja agradeço.

Comment: Que variáveis?.

Comment: Exemplo se eu uso o comando SET @x = 100;

Comment: Basicamente elimina com `SET @var = NULL;` (todo `SELECT @variavelnaoexistente` dá NULL de qq forma, você simplemente estará revertendo para a situação original)- Qual seria a motivação? Você sabe que é por sessão (conexão) que fica armazenado né? Se precisa limpar todas basta reconectar. O MySQL não fica acumulando essa informação.

Comment: Duvida resolvida. muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente elimina assim:

```
SET @var = NULL;
```

você simplemente estará revertendo a variável para a situação original (todo `SELECT @variavelnaoexistente` dá `NULL`).

O importante é você saber que é por sessão (conexão) que a informação é mantida. Se precisa limpar todas basta reconectar. O MySQL não fica acumulando essa informação de maneira persistente.

Para listar variáveis há o `SHOW VARIABLES` (e suas variações), mas este só mostra as variáveis internas pré-definidas, sejam globais ou de sessão.

Considerando que quem "cria" as @variáveis de usuário é o próprio usuário, provavelmente num caso de rara necessidade, ele mesmo pode rastrear o que criou.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas explicações;